# Where are a monster’s hit dice found in the stat block?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, hit-dice

I want to bring back to consciousness an Evil Mage that my PCs have successfully rendered unconscious.  My thought is that all could use a short rest and during this time the unconscious mage could roll some or all of his hit dice to regain HP (so as to continue with the PC party as a prisoner).  I’m thinking that the type and number of hit dice is found in parentheses next to Hit Points.

Example:

> Goblin
>   Hit Points: 7 (2d6)

Is it the case that goblins have two d6 hit dice?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### You are correct, it's the dice in parentheses

The dice component of the Hit Points line represent the monster's hit dice. This is implied, but not made explicit in the Introduction to the Monster Manual or in [Chapter 12 of the Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#HitPoints) under Hit Points.

> For example, if a monster has a Constitution of 12 (+1 modifier) and 2d8 Hit Dice, it has 2d8 + 2 hit points (average 11).

Comment: I’m working from the starter kit and could not find that thanks

Comment: @Greg0141its under the Hit Points section although it's not as explicit as I'd like

Comment: I saw the cited information and was able to make an educated guess, however, It was just that.  As you say, not spelled out clearly (particularly for the novice)