# How much HP does a Pact of the Chain Imp familiar recover on a Short Rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, hit-points, rests

I believe a Pact of the Chain [Imp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/imp) familiar uses the normal Imp stat block. So it has:

- Hit Points 10 (3d4 + 3)
- CON 13 (+1)
- Challenge 1 (200 XP)

**For purposes of recovering HP during [a Short Rest](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#ShortRest), how many hit dice does the Imp have, and what dice does it roll?**

---

Also, how is this determined, ie. how does this generalize to the other kinds of familiar?

---

I am asking this to get a RAW answer, if one can be found. I did not find any connection between monster HP and monster HD in my player books, and I am hoping the Monster Manual or DMG have something unambiguous.

My first guess, based on what I remember from some older editions of D&D, would have been that CR would be same as HD, but this does not make much sense when some of the 5e monsters have fractional CR.

Comment: Valid duplicate. LInking to specific rule I missed: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#HitPoints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The imp has 3 d4-sized hit dice and can spend them during a short rest like any other creature can.

As explored in the questions "[Where are a monster’s hit dice found in the stat block?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142279/28402)" and "[How do creatures spend Hit Dice after a short rest (if they can do so)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142297/28402)", a monster's hit dice can be determined from the dice expression used in their HP statistic, and then like any other creature they can spend those hit dice as per the normal rules for resting, including adding their constitution modifier. Further, the *Find Familiar* spell makes clear that a familiar's game statistics are exactly the same as a normal creature of that kind except for the very limited changes applied by the spell, none of which affect hit points, hit dice, or resting mechanics in any way.

Thus, your imp has 3 hit dice to spend when it rests and recovers 1d4+1 HP for each.

Comment: So, looking at your answer and the linked QA, this isn't actually explicitly said anywhere? This is just conjecture, that the numbers match: 3 dice plus 3xCON bonus must mean 3 HD. I guess this is as good as it gets then, though I was hoping for something a bit more concrete to show to the DM.

Comment: @Waki it's not conjecture, that is how the rules work, it's just not explicitly written down in one place but rather something you need to stitch together from multiple places. It'd be better if the monster manual spelled this out a bit better, but apparently the authors figured it'd be a bad idea to repeat general game rules there.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir The linked question about lobster hit dice spells it out explicitly. “For example, if a monster has a Constitution of 12 (+1 modifier) and 2d8 Hit Dice, it has 2d8 + 2 hit points (average 11).”

Comment: Re-reading... yeah, that quote is indeed an answer enough. Maybe have it added to this answer too, despite the duplicate.